# IWatch simulator not showing up

Tags: iphone, visibility, simulator, iso

I need a little help.
I'm trying to create an iWatch app with Xcode a Single View Project with AppleWatchKit.

Somehow the iWatch simulator is not visible just the iPhone 6 simulator.
Please help.
I have read a lot of posts but none of them helped.
Regards,
Krisz

Answer (score 0):

Select Simulator and click on Hardware from IOs simulator menu Bar. and show buttom of Hardware External Displays. Now click External Display then show List of device dimension with Apple Watch simulator. now select Apple Watch simulator according your need. I attach screen shoot. 
[image: Screen shoot for Iphone simulator]